# pymodbus: Modbus RTU read register call blocked & never woke up or Auto-reconnect to Modbus RTU device

Tags: python-3.x, pyserial, modbus, modbus-tcp, pymodbus

I am trying to create Modbus RTU client which will read data from serial port using **pymodbus** library. I am able to connect to Modbus RTU running on `COM2` in Windows10 & able to read data of different types like `Int32`, `Float`, etc.

**Issue:**

> After some time I've disconnected my device & checked the status of
>   ModbusClient. My client is connected to `COM2` port & trying to read
>   from the device which is not available & call for
>   `read_holding_registers` blocked.

**Environment:**

> Python: 3.6.5 
>   pymodbus: 2.1.0 
>   Windows: 10 64bit

According to me, it should throw an error something like below

```
[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionRefusedError'>: Connection was refused by other side: 10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

OR

[Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'pymodbus.exceptions.ConnectionException'>: Modbus Error: [Connection] Client is not connected
```

The above error I'm getting when disconnected from Modbus TCP device. But, there is no action done in case of Modbus RTU.

Below code handle connection lost & failed events:

```
from pymodbus.client.common import ModbusClientMixin
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class CustomModbusClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory, ModbusClientMixin):

    def buildProtocol(self, addr=None):
        modbusClientProtocol = CustomModbusClientProtocol()
        modbusClientProtocol.factory = self
        return modbusClientProtocol

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        logger.critical("Connection lost with device running on {0}:{1}.".format(modbusTcpDeviceIP, modbusTcpDevicePort))
        logger.critical("Root Cause : {0}".format(reason))
        connector.connect()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        logger.critical("Connection failed with device running on {0}:{1}.".format(modbusTcpDeviceIP, modbusTcpDevicePort))
        logger.critical("Root Cause : {0}".format(reason))
        connector.connect()
```

**My complete code is given here** : [ModbusRTUClient.py](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=16101963495941293625)

I've make sure availability of Modbus RTU device & raise an alerts if there is any issue with communication with device.

Does anyone have an idea how disconnection & re-connection of Modbus RTU device is handled ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing serial communications and TCP/IP ones. They are completely different. When using Modbus RTU, it works over serial lines (mostly it is RS-485 interface in industry, or RS-232 for configuration purposes).

In TCP/IP you have a logical channel (TCP), which is responsible for self-diagnostics and dropping errors when trying to read/write to unconnected endpoint.

With serial lines you just send the data to port (which is done regardless of whether someone on the other side is listening for it) and the only way to understand that your endpoint is down is timeout waiting for a reply.

By the way, there are some point when no reply doesnt mean the device is offline - broadcast messages are an excellent example. For some modbus devices you can broadcast time information on slave `0` and no reply would be granted.

Conclusion: with rtu devices there is no `connect/disconnect` procedure, you only speak in terms of request/reply.

Comment: Isn't there any mechanism by which we can identify whether device connected to serial port ? How can I use broadcast time information ? Should I wait for some time & then break the transaction if no reply within time ? Could you please guide me where should I go ?

Comment: The only way is getting reply from a device - no other mechanism could be used. Time broadcasting is available only for devices, supporting it - you have to refer to device mans. Yes, ofc, in serial communications you always setup a timeout with number of attempts; after they all fail, you consider device offline.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Let me try _timeout option with retry mechanism_. I'll get back to you in sometime with whatever result of this integration.

Comment: Hi @grapes, I've added `timeout` in my read data from ***Modbus RTU device*** call & handled it in failure block. It worked for me as expected. Thank you for directing me on right path. Accepting your answer because, it guide me to right direction. **Posting my solution as answer. It may help someone.**

Answer (score 0):

As @grapes said, only request/response format will work in case of `RTU` device communication. Thus, only option we have is to add `timeout` which will close the transaction once read timeout occurs.

> From the documentation of [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/18.4.0/), I found method named `addTimeout` You can check docs from [twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.addTimeout(...)](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/18.4.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.addTimeout.html) which allow to cancel transaction after the amount of time given as `timeout`.

Once request is timed out, it will pass control to `errorHandler` of `Deferred` object. Where you add re-connection logic by calling `connectionMade` method of `ModbusClientProtocol`, In my example, it is named as `CustomModbusClientProtocol`.

**My Working Code:**

Below is my complete solution for auto-reconnect to Modbus `RTU` device. Where I am trying to read `10` characters of `string` data from `RTU` device.

```
import logging
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

from pymodbus.client.async.twisted import ModbusClientProtocol
from pymodbus.constants import Endian
from pymodbus.factory import ClientDecoder
from pymodbus.payload import BinaryPayloadDecoder
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer
from serial import EIGHTBITS
from serial import PARITY_EVEN
from serial import STOPBITS_ONE
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.internet import serialport, reactor

FORMAT = ('%(asctime)-15s %(threadName)-15s '
      '%(levelname)-8s %(module)-15s:%(lineno)-8s %(message)s')
logging.basicConfig(format=FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def readDevices(modbusRTUDevice):
    deviceIP = modbusRTUDevice["ip"]
    devicePort = modbusRTUDevice["port"]
    logger.info("Connecting to Modbus RTU device at address {0}".format(deviceIP + ":" + str(devicePort)))
    modbusClientFactory = CustomModbusClientFactory()
    modbusClientFactory.address = deviceIP
    modbusClientFactory.modbusDevice = modbusRTUDevice
    SerialModbusClient(modbusClientFactory, devicePort, reactor, baudrate=9600, bytesize=EIGHTBITS,
                   parity=PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=STOPBITS_ONE, xonxoff=0, rtscts=0)
    Thread(target=reactor.run, args=(False,)).start()  # @UndefinedVariable


class SerialModbusClient(serialport.SerialPort):

    def __init__(self, factory, *args, **kwargs):
        serialport.SerialPort.__init__(self, factory.buildProtocol(), *args, **kwargs)


class CustomModbusClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    modbusDevice = {}

    def buildProtocol(self, addr=None):
        modbusClientProtocol = CustomModbusClientProtocol()
        modbusClientProtocol.factory = self
        modbusClientProtocol.modbusDevice = self.modbusDevice
        return modbusClientProtocol

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        modbusTcpDeviceIP = self.modbusDevice["ip"]
        modbusTcpDevicePort = self.modbusDevice["port"]
        logger.critical("Connection lost with device running on {0}:{1}.".format(modbusTcpDeviceIP, modbusTcpDevicePort))
        logger.critical("Root Cause : {0}".format(reason))
        connector.connect()

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        modbusTcpDeviceIP = self.modbusDevice["ip"]
        modbusTcpDevicePort = self.modbusDevice["port"]
        logger.critical("Connection failed with device running on {0}:{1}.".format(modbusTcpDeviceIP, modbusTcpDevicePort))
        logger.critical("Root Cause : {0}".format(reason))
        connector.connect()


class CustomModbusClientProtocol(ModbusClientProtocol):

    def connectionMade(self):
        framer = ModbusRtuFramer(ClientDecoder(), client=None)
        ModbusClientProtocol.__init__(self, framer)
        ModbusClientProtocol.connectionMade(self)
        deviceIP = self.modbusDevice["ip"]
        devicePort = self.modbusDevice["port"]
        logger.info("Modbus RTU device connected at address {0}".format(deviceIP + ":" + str(devicePort)))
        reactor.callLater(5, self.read)  # @UndefinedVariable

    def read(self):
        deviceIP = self.modbusDevice["ip"]
        devicePort = self.modbusDevice["port"]
        slaveAddress = self.modbusDevice["slaveAddress"]
        deviceReadTimeout = self.modbusDevice["readTimeoutInSeconds"]
        logger.info("Reading holding registers of Modbus RTU device at address {0}...".format(deviceIP + ":" + str(devicePort)))
        deferred = self.read_holding_registers(0, 5, unit=slaveAddress)
        deferred.addCallbacks(self.requestFetched, self.requestNotFetched)
        deferred.addTimeout(deviceReadTimeout, reactor)

    def requestNotFetched(self, error):
        logger.info("Error reading registers of Modbus RTU device : {0}".format(error))
        logger.error("Trying reconnect in next {0} seconds...".format(5))
        reactor.callLater(5, self.connectionMade)  # @UndefinedVariable

    def requestFetched(self, response):
        logger.info("Inside request fetched...")
        decoder = BinaryPayloadDecoder.fromRegisters(response.registers, byteorder=Endian.Big, wordorder=Endian.Big)
        skipBytesCount = 0
        decoder.skip_bytes(skipBytesCount)
        registerValue = decoder.decode_string(10).decode()
        skipBytesCount += 10
        logger.info("Sensor updated to value '{0}'.".format(registerValue))
        reactor.callLater(5, self.read)  # @UndefinedVariable


readDevices({"ip": "127.0.0.1", "port": "COM2", "slaveAddress": 1, "readTimeoutInSeconds": 30})
```

**Output:**

```
2019-02-19 15:40:02,533 MainThread      INFO     TestRTU:26       Connecting to Modbus RTU device at address 127.0.0.1:COM2
2019-02-19 15:40:02,536 MainThread      INFO     TestRTU:73       Modbus RTU device connected at address 127.0.0.1:COM2
2019-02-19 15:40:07,541 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:81       Reading holding registers of Modbus RTU device at address 127.0.0.1:COM2...
2019-02-19 15:40:07,662 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:92       Inside request fetched...
2019-02-19 15:40:07,662 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:98       Sensor updated to value 'abcdefghij'.


2019-02-19 15:40:12,662 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:81       Reading holding registers of Modbus RTU device at address 127.0.0.1:COM2...
2019-02-19 15:40:12,773 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:92       Inside request fetched...
2019-02-19 15:40:12,773 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:98       Sensor updated to value 'abcdefghij'.


2019-02-19 15:40:17,773 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:81       Reading holding registers of Modbus RTU device at address 127.0.0.1:COM2...
2019-02-19 15:40:47,773 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:87       Error reading registers of Modbus RTU device : [Failure instance: Traceback (failure with no frames): <class 'twisted.internet.defer.CancelledError'>:]
2019-02-19 15:40:47,773 Thread-2        ERROR    TestRTU:88       Trying to reconnect in next 5 seconds...


2019-02-19 15:40:52,780 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:73       Modbus RTU device connected at address logger127.0.0.1:COM2
2019-02-19 15:40:57,784 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:81       Reading holding registers of Modbus RTU device at address 127.0.0.1:COM2...
2019-02-19 15:40:57,996 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:92       Inside request fetched...
2019-02-19 15:40:57,996 Thread-2        INFO     TestRTU:98       Sensor updated to value 'abcdefghij'.
```

I hope this helps someone in future.